# remove a duplicate element(with specific value) from xml using linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

If I have this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<super>
  <A value="1234">
    <a1 xx="000" yy="dddddd" />
    <a1 xx="111" yy="eeeeee" />
    <a1 xx="222" yy="ffffff"/>
  </A>
</super>
```

and I need to remove a1 element (that have xx=222) completely. why this won't happen using my code?? i realized that it will delete it only if it was placed the first element(i.e, if i want to delete a1 that have x=000 , it will delete it since its the first one), why is that??

what wrong with the code ??

```
var employee = from emp in element.Elements("A")
    where (string)emp.Element("a1").Attribute("xx") == "222"
    select emp.Element("a1");

foreach (var empployee_1 in employee)
{
    empployee_1.Remove();
}

element.Save(@"TheLocation");
```

thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this,

```
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Xml.Linq;
 using System.Xml.XPath;

 var element = XElement.Parse(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
                            <super>
                              <A value=""1234"">
                                <a1 xx=""000"" yy=""dddddd"" />
                                <a1 xx=""111"" yy=""eeeeee"" />
                                <a1 xx=""222"" yy=""ffffff""/>
                              </A>
                            </super>");

  // select all the a1's that have xx = 222
  var a1Elements = element.XPathSelectElement("A/a1[@xx='222']"); 

  if (a1Elements != null)
     a1Elements.Remove();

  Console.WriteLine(element);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 IEnumerable<XElement> element = from element1 in doc.Elements("A") select element1;            

            foreach (XElement xe in element.Elements())
            {
                if (xe.Attribute("xx").Value == "222")
                    xe.Remove();
            }
```